# Multiple Guard on single route React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Can you put multiple route guards on one route? I'm trying to put two guards (one is auth and other is roleguard) on `"/main/dashboard"` so that it can only be accessed by specific roles. Below is my code. It's not working.

```
{
  path: '/main/dashboard',
  element: (
    <AuthGuard>
      <RoleGuard role={GUEST}>
        <DashboardLayout />
      </RoleGuard>
    </AuthGuard>
  ),
  children: [
    { element: <Navigate to={LoginPath()} replace />, index: true },
    { path: 'dashboard', element: <Dashboard /> },
  ],
},
```

RoleGuard Component here

```
  import { ReactNode } from 'react';
  import useAuth from 'src/hooks/useAuth';
  import LoginView from 'src/components/auth/login/LoginView';


  type RoleBasedGuardProp = {
  role: string;
  children: ReactNode | string;
  };

  export default function RoleBasedGuard({ role, children }:  RoleBasedGuardProp) {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  if (user?.account_type === role) {
   return <LoginView />;
  }
  return <>{children}</>;
  }
```

AuthGuard Component Here (Basically authentication for users)

```
import { useState, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';
import LoginView from 'src/components/auth/login/LoginView';
import LoadingScreen from '../components/LoadingScreen';


 type AuthGuardProps = {
 children: ReactNode;
 };

 export default function AuthGuard({ children }: AuthGuardProps) {
  const { isAuthenticated, isInitialized } = useAuth();
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const [requestedLocation, setRequestedLocation] = useState<string | null>(null);

  if (!isInitialized) {
  return <LoadingScreen />;
  }

  if (!isAuthenticated) {
  if (pathname !== requestedLocation) {
  setRequestedLocation(pathname);
  }
 return <LoginView />;
 }

 if (requestedLocation && pathname !== requestedLocation) {
 setRequestedLocation(null);
 return <Navigate to={requestedLocation} />;
 }

 return <>{children}</>;
 }
```

Comment: What are `AuthGuard` and `RoleGuard` components? Can you share these components' code? Or if these are imported from a library, share how they are imported and from what package/library?

Comment: AuthGuard(only authenticated users can access) , RoleGuard(if Guest you cannot access "/main/dashboard")

Comment: Sorry, I gathered what purpose they were serving, but we need to know what the components do to understand why wrapping them like this doesn't work. In other words, access to official source code and documentation could help us understand where your code went sideways. Can you also more clearly explain what exactly isn't working and what the expected behavior should be, and what debugging steps you have already taken to identify the issue?

Comment: AuthGuard and RoleGuard code has been added updated

Comment: Thanks, taking a look again. In the mean time, can you provide more details about what isn't working as expected? Anything that could give us a clue where to focus?

Comment: the  RoleGuard Works but then Admin users cannot access '/main/dashboard'

Comment: I don't see any overt issue(s) in the code you have shared. Would it be possible for you to create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?